# Using preg_replace to remove unwanted characters but need to keep '.'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using php preg_replace to sanitise my upload file, i want to remove any unwanted characters like (&?/\~{}[ ] - thats removing whitespace as well) etc, but i don't want to remove '.' (full stop/period) because it's stripping out the file extension.

I've been scouring the internet, but just keep on finding the either remove all special characters or overly complicated regex.

Heres my current code, but as you can see, it's removing '.'

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', "{$uploadedFile}");
```

There must be an answer i've missed as it seems a fairly straight forward request, does anyone know what i'd need to include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A character class lists the characters you want to allow/disallow. So add the `.` inside your character class and you should be good to go.

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", '', "{$uploadedFile}");
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bE5qI4/1

For additional information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Also additionally worth noting:

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).

Comment: Chris, that worked a treat, i knew there would be a simple solution, thanks for the help and the link to charclass